# Has galaxy merger and universe expansion been proven?

Tags: gravity, space-expansion, galaxies

I understand the basic argument for hierarchical merging of galaxies during expansion of the universe. I also understand peculiar motion and the Hubble flow. So I understand what's going on with Andromeda and the Local Group (sufficiently, I think). But it's not intuitive that mergers have occurred on the scale that they must have, to create the huge galaxies that dominate the universe today, while expansion has continued. While at the same time that observed galaxies are basically passive...just carried along in the Hubble flow. So my question is: has this been robustly tested in equations? Which should be possible if know the rate expansion at each period roughly and we know the size of galaxies and their separation, roughly. We should at least be able to work out some minimums and maximums. So has this been done and can anyone talk about it?

Comment: Are you looking for examples of galaxy mergers? They do exist.

Answer (score -1):

So it's October and no one has apparently answered this. I think the short answer is "no." The whole premise of the expanding universe is based on Hubble's observations of the red-shift. However, expansion is just an interpretation -- it has not been observed. The math to get galaxies colliding and even forming as early as they appear to be is simply not aligned with the Hubble red-shift data. Thus, some have proposed adding dark matter / energy and other tricks like inflation to get the math to work. In my view, the original interpretation of the red-shift is wrong. The big-bang is wrong and we need to start over to figure out what is causing the red-shift.

Comment: Actually, Hubble didn't do the red-shift observations. Vesto Slipher measured the red shift.  Hubble helped measure the distances.  Lemaitre, and later Hubble, correlated the red shift with the distance. The database for these measurements has expanded well beyond the info Hubble had and it **strongly** supports the idea of expansion.  Show some data which refutes it.

Comment: Hello Bill N. Slipher nobserved all or most galaxies were red shifted. This much was going to be noticed by the first observations at sufficient resolution, by whoever.  The really important, non-trivial discoveries were the correlates and that was Hubble. By the way he never accepted expansion as the explanation.

Comment: Hi user95492 - thank you for being the only person to try for an answer :O) Could you say a bit more about the unaligned relation of the datasets (of redshift etc) and the theoretical work so far - or the problems involved - in galaxy merger etc.